# RHEL 5.2 Rescue Mode

Tags: linux, virtualization, redhat, hyper-v, boot

I'm trying to get a RHEL 5.2 VM from VMWare to HyperV.
Currently the VM won't boot due to the lack of appropriate drivers in the initial RAM disk image so I need to run Initramfs in rescue to create a new RAM disk.

The problem is I cant seem to get into rescue mode using the RHEL 5.2 ISO.

When I boot to the ISO I can head into rescue mode... it tells me that "Your boot disk is the first disk in a two-part rescue disk set. The second disk required for rescue mode must be created from the rescue.img image file, located in the images directory of the RedHat Linux CD".

Sure enough, if I browse the ISO there is an images folder and in there is rescue.img.

Bear in mind I'm working on hyperV, I basically converted that .img file to a virtual floppy disk (.vfd) file and mounted it when prompted ("Insert root floppy disk to be loaded into ramdisk and press ENTER"), but it simply comes back with "Couldnt find valid ramdisk image starting at 0".

I've been unable to boot this VM for 3 days so far and I'm getting kind of desperate... can anyone help me at all or point me in the right direction?

It may be worth mentioning, I need Kernel 2.6.18-419.el5.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too young to know much about RHEL 5 rescue, but if you have access to a RHEL 6 ISO, that might get you into a working rescue environment. I frequently rescue RHEL 6.x systems with a RHEL 7.2 ISO.

Comment: I've got into a rescue environment using media of Redhat 5.8, it mounts the system in /mnt/sysimage, but the boot folder is empty, which is pretty strange... that stops me in my tracks trying to 'mkinitrd -f -v /boot/initrd-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)' because theres nothing in boot.